# Prevent older version from installing over newer version

Tags: java, install4j

I would like to set some version validation to prevent end users from installing an older version on top of a newer version. Ex. prevent version 1 from installing when version 3 has been installed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Install4j v5.1.15

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of your installer to validate the version that has already been installed.

The following code snippet demonstrates how to validate against more recent versions if they are simple integers:

```
// The value returned by context.getInstallationDirectory() will be the last 
// installation directory if the user has already installed the application
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(context.getInstallationDirectory());

if (applicationInfo == null) {
  // The application has never been installed before
    return true;
}

if (Integer.parseInt(applicationInfo.getVersion()) > 
   Integer.parseInt(context.getVersion())) {
    Util.showErrorMessage("A more recent version has already been" +
    " installed in this directory");
    // By returning "false", the action will fail and the installer will quit.
    // Note that you have to set the "Failure strategy" property of your 
// "Run script" action to "Quit on error", otherwise the installer will continue.
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Versions are more complex such as 10.6.5. What changes would I need?  I'm getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException: as is.

Comment: It's not in the API, but you can use the internal method `com.install4j.runtime.util.VersionCheck.checkCompatible(version1, version2)` which will return true if `version1` is lower than `version2`.